# Project Tango Unable To Instantiate Activity

Tags: project, instantiation, tango

Application used to work on older software revisions, but now crashes on startup. My guess is that this isn't a problem with Unity, since I can easily work with other projects, but an issue with wither my device or how I have things set up in the editor. Any help is appreciated! Here is the error I am receiving:

```
`I/ActivityManager( 900): Start proc com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR for activity com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity: pid=5029 uid=10118 gids={50118, 3003, 1028, 1015}

D/AndroidRuntime( 5029): Shutting down VM

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): Process: com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR, PID: 5029

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR-2, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR-2, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): ... 9 more

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): ... 12 more

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class "Lcom/google/unity/GoogleUnityActivity;" not found

E/AndroidRuntime( 5029): ... 16 more

W/ActivityManager( 900): Force finishing activity com.OwlArrowGames.TangoSportsVR/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity`
```